# tracing context switches of a process on linux

Tags: linux

I need to monitor the context switches of a process and find out the reasons of the context-switches such as the specific kernel daemon causing the switch. I have seen related posts but I didn't find the answers satisfactory. I tried pidstat but it only shows the number of context switches. I would like to do this without recompiling the kernel for some profiling tool unless necessary.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it really make sense; [context switches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) are happening *inside the kernel*, not "inside the process". They are affecting some process. And most of them are not related to a kernel task. They happen "nearly inside" the scheduler. Most context switches are related to jiffies: running tasks are rescheduled after a small quantum of time (e.g. 20 milliseconds).

And the information about each traced context switch should go somewhere, i.e. into some process, which will also get context switched, ...

Comment: I understand that context switches happen when time quantum expires.But there are other reasons too. I would like to monitor all such context switches whether they are due to jiffies or some higher priority process being scheduled.